# Ricci Curvature under uniform scaling

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

While reading about the Ricci flow, I've ran into the following statement:

> It is worth pointing out here that the Ricci tensor is invariant under uniform
> scaling of the metric.

This quote was provided as part of a simple example - Ricci flow of an Einstein manifold of constant $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. See "Lectures on the Ricci Flow", P. Topping, for more context.

For some reason, that surprised me. So I've tried to prove it. I've obviously got it wrong, but I can't see where. Here's my go at it.

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $\tilde{g}=\lambda g$, be an alternative metric.
From the  Koszul formula we have:
$$
\begin{align}
2\tilde{g}(\tilde{\nabla}_X Y ,Z) 
                           &= X (\tilde{g}(Y,Z)) + Y (\tilde{g}(X,Z)) - Z (\tilde{g}(X,Y)) \\
                           &-\tilde{g}([Y,X],Z) - \tilde{g}([X,Z],Y) - \tilde{g}([Y,Z],X) \\ 
                           &= \lambda  \{X (g(Y,Z)) + Y (g(X,Z)) - Z (g(X,Y)) \\
                           &-g([Y,X],Z) - g([X,Z],Y) - g([Y,Z],X) \} \\
                           &= \lambda 2g(\nabla_X Y ,Z)
\end{align}
$$
So:
$$ 
\lambda g (\tilde{\nabla}_X Y ,Z) = \lambda g (\nabla_X Y ,Z) 
$$

By the uniqueness of the connection, we have $\tilde{\nabla} = \nabla$, and in particular:

$$ \tilde{R}(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z -\nabla_{[X,Y]} Z = R(X,Y)Z $$

So far, it all sounds sort of sensible to me - using that identity with the uniform scaling of the sphere will lead to the desired change in sectional curvature.
But if all that was true, we'd have:
$$ 
\tilde{Ric}(v,w) = \sum_{i} \tilde{g}(R(e_i , v)w ,e_i)  = \sum_{i} \lambda g(R(e_i , v)w ,e_i) = \lambda Ric (v,w) 
$$

And not:

$$ Ric = \tilde{Ric} $$

What did I get wrong? Is there some geometric heuristic that you can offer as for why would Ricci curvature stays invariant under scaling?

Comment: I believe that everything you did is correct. The Ricci tensors are the same, but to calculate the Ricci curvature you have to use unit vectors in the respective metrics, hence if $v$ is a unit vector w.r.t $\tilde g$ we have to calculate $\text{Ric}( \sqrt{\lambda} v,  \sqrt{\lambda} v)$ for the Ricci curvature in direction $v$ w.r.t. the metric $g$ which gives us that $\tilde{r} = r$ for the Ricci curvatures.

Comment: Seems like you're right. Would you post your answer?

Comment: Actually you have a problem at ţhe end: an orthonormal basis $e_i$ w.r.t. $g$ stops being orthonormal after rescaling

Comment: @user8268, Is it not the same issue pointed out by @Lukas?

Comment: no; the 2 Ricci tensors are equal

Comment: This is most easily done using coordinates and avoiding unit vectors. First, observe that Christoffel symbols are scale invariant. Second, using the definition above of the Riemann curvature with coordinate vector fields, you get a formula for the curvature tensor as a $(3,1)$ tensor that contains only Christoffel symbols and their partial derivatives. Therefore this is also scale invariant. The Ricci tensor with respect to coordinates is now a sum that does not use the metric. Therefore, it is scale invariant.

Comment: Or, in your calculation, you could write: $$\mathrm{Ric}(v,w)=\langle\omega^i,R(f_i,v)w\rangle$$ where $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ is any basis of the tangent space and $(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^n)$ is the dual basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit because the original answer was wrong**: My original answer was wrong in its claim that the Ricci tensor would scale. By definition, we have $Ric(X,Y)= \text{tr}(Z \mapsto R(Z,X)Y)$ where $R$ is the Riemannian curvature tensor. So as the curvature tensor stays the same, so does the Ricci tensor. The mistake in the calculation above was that the formula $\text{Ric}(X,Y)= \sum_{i=1}^n g(R(E_i, X)Y, E_i)$ is only true if $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is an orthonormal basis of the tangent space with respect to $g$. Now if that is the case we have that $\{\frac{E_i}{\sqrt \lambda}\}_{i=1}^n$ is an orthonormal base with respect to $\tilde g$ and therefore
$$\tilde{\text{Ric}}(v,w) = \sum \tilde g(R(\frac{E_i}{\sqrt \lambda}, v)w, \frac{E_i}{\sqrt \lambda}) = \sum \lambda g(R(\frac{E_i}{\sqrt \lambda}, v)w, \frac{E_i}{\sqrt \lambda}) = \sum g(R(E_i,v)w, E_i) = \text{Ric}(v,w).$$
My comment on the Ricci curvature staying the same under scaling stays true however.

**Original, wrong answer**: In order to calculate the Ricci curvature in a direction $v$ we always have to normalise the vector.  If we denote by $r$ and $\tilde r$ the respective Ricci curvatures and choose $v$ to have unit length w.r.t. $\tilde g$ then we have

$$\tilde r(v)=\tilde{\text{Ric}}(\frac{v}{||v||_{\tilde g}},\frac{v}{||v||_{\tilde g}}) =\tilde{\text{Ric}}(v,v) = \lambda \text{Ric}(v,v) =\text{Ric}(\sqrt \lambda v, \sqrt \lambda v)= \text{Ric}(\frac{v}{||v||_{ g}},\frac{v}{||v||_{ g}}) =r(v) $$
because $||v||^2_g = \langle v, v \rangle_g = \frac{1}{\lambda} \langle v,v \rangle_{\tilde g}= \frac{1}{\lambda}$ so that $\sqrt \lambda v$ is the normalized version of $v$ w.r.t. $g$.

Hence the Ricci Curvature stays the same if we scale the metric even though the Ricci tensor $\text{Ric}(v,w)$ scales in the same way as the metric.

Comment: This answer is _wrong_, since $\widetilde{Ric} = Ric$. Your calculations are OK, but @NG_ made a mistake in his. In the end $Ric$ is defined as a partial trace of the curvature tensor (no metric needed), and the curvature tensor doesn't change under rescaling, just as NG_ noticed.

Comment: Given vector fields $x,y$, let $\rho(v)$  be the partial bind of the curvature tensor $v \mapsto R(v,x,y)$. The trace for $\rho$ is the definition of $Ric(x,y)$. Mark the $i$ summand of the $\rho$ matrix $\rho_{ii}$. Then, given an orthonormal basis $e_i$, we have: $\rho_{ii} = g(\rho(e_i),e_i)$, hence the appearance of the metric in the definition of the Ricci tensor. Is this wrong, @user8268?

Comment: @NG_ as you see, the definition via trace uses only $R$, not $g$. What you write next is true, but notice that an orthonormal basis will stop being orthonormal if you rescale the metric.

Comment: Ah, I finally see the issue you're pointing at @user8268. I thank you for your patience. Lukas, note that the third equality, $\tilde{Ric}(v,v) = \lambda Ric(v,v)$ contradicts what we're trying to prove here.